# How to organize project to get product price for specific user type?

Tags: django

To illustrate the problem I propose to consider a simplified version of my application.

Suppose there is a product model:

```
# products/models.py
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    retail_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
```

And custom user model:

```
# authentication/models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class ClientType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    part_of_retail_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)


class Client(AbstractUser):  # custom user model
    client_type = models.ForeignKey(ClientType)
```

I want to be able to get a special price for a certain type of user in the template:

```
{% for product in products %}
   {{ product.user_price }}
{% endfor %}
```

Authorized users price is equal to the product of product.retail_price and request.user.client_type.part_of_retail_price, for unauthorized just product.retail_price.

What is the best way to implement it? I would appreciate any hints and help.

Comment: One method would be to write a custom filter that multiplies the value with the correct factor. You can then use it in your template like `{{ product.user_price|user_price }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need the value for displaying one or a few `Client` instances at a time, easiest is to use a template filter like `{{ product.user_price|user_price }}` as suggested on the comment by @Selcuk.

If you need the value in a `QuerySet` to work with (sorting etc.), then use a Manager, together with `annotate()` and the `ExpressionWrapper()`.

```
class ProductManager(models.Manager):

    def for_user(self, user):
        # Calculate the price here
        user_price = user.user.client_type.part_of_retail_price

        return self.annotate(user_price=ExpressionWrapper(
            Value(user_price), output_field=FloatField()))

class Product(models.Model):
    # ...

    objects = ProductManager()
```

Then, when you load the Product QuerySet in your view, add the current user

```
products = Product.objects.all().for_user(request.user)
```

to add the `user_price` to a regular QuerySet, and you can use it in your templates as required.

```
{% for product in products %}
   {{ product.user_price }}
{% endfor %}
```

- more on [Django Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/)
- more on [annotations and expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/)